# Filter two Future[Seq] with for comprehension scala

Tags: scala, for-comprehension, flatmap

I have some functions which returns list of tuple elements(Int, Int) with future. For simplicity I will define two futures

```
  val f1 = Future {
    List((8, 3), (2, 1), (4, 2), (3, 4))
  }
  val f2 = Future {
    List((2, 3), (5, 1), (7, 9))
  }
```

I want to filter and get the elements form these two future lists with below criteria.

> Tuples which contains same element in second position

In this scenario output should be

```
List(((2,1),(5,1)), ((8,3),(2,3)))
```

I can do this with normal lists(without futures) with for comprehension like below

```
val l1 = List((4, 2), (3, 4), (2, 1), (8, 3))
val l2 = List((2, 3), (5, 1), (7, 9))

val o = for {
  a <- l1
  b <- l2 if a._2 == b._2
} yield (a, b)
```

How to do it with futures?

Comment: "for compression" ?

Comment: @pedrofurla edited -> comprehension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additional solution if you want to use full for comprehension:

```
val o2 = for {
  l1 <- f1
  l2 <- f2
} yield for {
  a <- l1
  b <- l2 if a._2 == b._2
} yield (a,b)
```

Of course you will have Future here, so you need to await for result or pass it further to something which will process it

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be the `ListT` monad transformer from scalaz ([although it violates the associative law](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/issues/921)):

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scalaz.Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val f1 = Future {
    List((8, 3), (2, 1), (4, 2), (3, 4))
  }

  val f2 = Future {
    List((2, 3), (5, 1), (7, 9))
  }

  val first = ListT[Future, (Int, Int)](f1)
  val second = ListT[Future, (Int, Int)](f2)

  val res = for {
    a <- first
    b <- second if a._2 == b._2
  } yield (a, b)

  println(Await.result(res.run, 3 seconds))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Scala 2.12 adds a `zipWith` to `Future`:

```
f1.zipWith(f2) {
  (l1, l2) => for {
    a <- l1
    b <- l2 if a._2 == b._2
  } yield (a, b)
}
```

For more information, see this blog post: http://viktorklang.com/blog/Futures-in-Scala-2.12-part-2.html